# Prevent pyspark from using in-memory session/docker

Tags: pyspark

We are looking into using Spark as big data processing framework in Azure Synapse Analytics with notebooks. I want to set up a local development environment/sandbox on my own computer similar to that, interacting with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2.

- For installing Spark I'm using WSL with a Ubuntu distro (Spark seems to be easier to manage in linux)
- For notebooks I'm using jupyter notebook with Anaconda

Both components work fine by themself but I can't manage to connect the notebook to my local sparkcluster in WSL. I tried the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local[1]") \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

When examining the `spark` object it outputs

```
SparkSession - in-memory
SparkContext
Spark UI
Version v3.3.0
Master local[1]
AppName Python Spark SQL basic example
```

The spark-ui link points to http://host.docker.internal:4040/jobs/, Also when examining the UI for spark in WSL I can't see any connection. I think there is something I'm missing or not understanding with how pyspark works. Any help would be much appreciated to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are connecting to local instance which is in this case native Windows running jupyter:

```
.master("local[1]")
```

Instead, you should connect to your WSL cluster:

```
.master("spark://localhost:7077")  # assuming default port
```

Comment: During startup I get the following url to the wsl cluster, I tried both `spark://localhost:7077` and `spark://LAPTOP-DDG1NSOH.localdomain:7077` but this throws a java-error:
````
An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.registerBlockManager(BlockManagerMaster.scala:79)
...
````

Comment: Can you try with some other random port (7070 or 7090) to see if you get a different error? You could also try running jupyter server inside WSL and see if that changes anything.

Comment: No, changing the port doesn't make a diference. Yes I think it will work if I run jupyter in WSL since pyspark works when I start it from inside WSL. I guess it's more of a workaround but still an option. I think your answer is the solution to my original questions and this is a new problem. Thanks for the help, will mark as solution!